# binary LP vs. integer LP

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I wonder why there is a difference between the following linear programs. They are written in the [LP file format](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp-format.htm). I would assume that `x=1` would be the optimal solution in both cases.

Program A:

```
min: x;
x >= 1;
bin x;
```

Output:

```
Value of objective function: 0

Actual values of the variables:
x                               0
```

Program B (simulates the binary constraint with the integer constrain and two additional constrains):

```
min: x;
x >= 1;
x <= 1;
x >= 0;
int x;
```

Output:

```
Value of objective function: 1.00000000

Actual values of the variables:
x                               1
```

Comment: For some reason it helps to add an "optional constraint name". I start to think that this might be a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a small quirk of `lpSove` having to do with single variable constraints.

In your Problem A, setting 'bin x' ends up overriding the constraint 'x >=1.' That is why 0 is given as the optimal solution.

From the [documentation](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp-format.htm):

> Note that for bounds on variables, you should not put labels before
>   them. This is because lp_solve then makes this an extra restriction.
>   If you don't put a label before single variables then lp_solve doesn't
>   have to create an extra row for bounds on variables, resulting in better performance.
>
> So it is better to write:
>
> ```
>  x1 >= 1;
> ```
>
> than
>
> ```
>  r_x1: x1 >= 1;
> ```
>
> Note that this is only for single variables, so
>       myrow: x1 + x2 >= 2;
>
> performs as well as
>
> ```
> x1 + x2 >= 2;
> ```

In your Problem A, you have a single variable constraint. When it is not explicitly named, the 'bin' declaration overrides that constraint. As you rightly point out, if you make the constraint explicit, by *naming it*, then lpSolve will create a new row for x1, thus honoring the constraint and the 'bin' cannot override it.

```
min: x;
a: x >= 1.0;
bin x;
```

will give you:

```
Value of objective function: 1.00000000

Actual values of the variables:
x                               1
```

Comment: I can't read from the documentation, that `bin` overwrites any constrains. Is this behavior intended?